# python - decimal into fraction divided by 1

Tags: python, fractions

I need to convert a decimal into fraction even if it's divided by 1.
I tried using fractions module, but it gives, say, 3 instead of 3/1, 5 instead of 5/1 etc. So I was wondering if there is any possibility to get this kind of fraction using fractions module or something else?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: When I do `print(fractions.Fraction(5))` I get the output `Fraction(5, 1)`. Isn't that what you're looking for? Or do you specifically want to format the output to be something like `5/1`?

Comment: Yes I need exactly the format like "5/1".

Comment: When you say "**it** gives, say 3 instead of 3/1", what precisely is **it**? What function do you invoke? Please reduce your program to the shortested **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Copy-paste that short program (3-5 lines, I should think) into your question. Include the expected and actual output. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string formatting to achieve what you want.

```
from fractions import Fraction
no = Fraction(3, 1)

str_no = "{0}/{1}".format(no.numerator, no.denominator)
print(str_no)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the class's `__str__` to get the behavior your like:

```
import fractions

class Fraction(fractions.Fraction):
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.numerator, self.denominator)


x = Fraction('6/2')
print(x)
x = Fraction('1.5')
print(x)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 x.py 
3/1
3/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

Check if the decimal is a whole number using `is_digit` then add a `/1` in if so.

```
import fractions

for v in [2.0, 0.1, 0.5, 1.5, 2.0 ]:
    if v.is_integer():
        print('{} = {}/1'.format(v, fractions.Fraction.from_float(v)))
    else:
        print('{} = {}'.format(v, fractions.Fraction.from_float(v)))
```

output:

```
2.0 = 2/1
0.1 = 3602879701896397/36028797018963968
0.5 = 1/2
1.5 = 3/2
2.0 = 2/1
```